# Socket disconnection in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, sockets, tcp

I need some help in IOS Socket programming. I have implemented a successful TCP Socket connection between IOS and a Java Server, however I found that it is imposible to reconnect it after the socket fails (I disconnect my network and reconnect it).

That's the code I use to open the streams:

```
- (void)initCommunication{
@try {
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 4454, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    //Asignamos los delegates
    inputStream.delegate = self;
    outputStream.delegate = self;  

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    connected = true;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    connected = false;
    NSLog(@"Error connecting socket: %@", exception.reason);
    [self checkConnection];
}
}
```

And when I receive a NSStreamEventErrorOccurred or a NSStreamEventEndEncountered I try to close the connection and reconnect again.

I close it with:

```
-(void) close{

[inputStream close];
[inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream close];
[outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream setDelegate:nil];
inputStream = nil;
[outputStream setDelegate:nil];
outputStream = nil;

connected = false;
}
```

The problem is that the socket is not reconnecting again... I am thinking on using SmallSockets or CocoaAsyncSockets to see if I can reconnect the socket... Do you see any implementation problem? Do you recommend using SmallSockets or CocoaAsyncSockets??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What error do you get on reconnect? Also, are you sure that the server is listening properly (e.g., can you connect to it with netcat from your Mac, disconnect, and immediately reconnect)?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using ARC, right?

Comment: Yes I am using ARC, that's why there are no releases on my code... however I receive everything ok on the Server part, so I can exchange packets between both parts...the problem come when I try to reconnect when I force a disconnect... I have been able to send again but not to receive. I will put some more information about the sockets events I receive...

Comment: I am doing the same in Android without problems, so I am sure it is a IOS problem... :S

Comment: I don't know why I can "open" two sockets streams when there is no active server on the other side...why does it happen? after that i get blocked when I try to write on the outputstream...

Comment: You may be unable to reconnect for the same reason that the original connection failed. You need to provide more detail about both failure modes.

Comment: It failed when I force a disconnection, because I want to be sure that the app is able to reconnect when the device lose coverage... I have been able to implement it with asynccocoasockets without problems.

Comment: I didn't receive anything from the server whe it failed, it is like you cannot open it again. I force the disconenction stopping my server and then starting it again and taking out network communication from my computer...why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I did implement it with CocoaAsyncSockets https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket and it was really easy doing a reconnection with this socket.

First I initialize the socket object:

```
socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

To connect I use:

```
NSError *err = nil;
if ([socket connectToHost:@"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" onPort:YYYY error:&err])
{
NSLog(@"Connection performed!");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"Unable to connect: %@", err);
}
```

And then you can use the delegate to do reconnection whenever it failed:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
NSLog(@"Socket:DidConnectToHost: %@ Port: %hu", host, port);

connected = YES;
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
NSLog(@"SocketDidDisconnect:WithError: %@", err);   
    connected = NO;
    //We will try to reconnect
    [self checkConnection];
}

- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    [self processReceivedData:data];
    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

I found very easy to use that library. I hope that helps anyone.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great framework, but socketDidDisconnect does not seem to be called on iOS 6... :(

Comment: Sorry, It does work when using GCDAsyncSocket. I was using AsyncSocket instead...

Comment: Glad you found it ;), it resolved my troubles with other frameworks